# Screen Flickering and Interference after Waking up Laptop

Tags: screen, flicker

Here's a link to a short video of what's happening:
[Screen interference](https://youtu.be/Y-Wb95sfuq8)
Probably about half the time I wake my laptop up after it has gone into suspension, my screen starts going crazy. The search bar flickers on and off, and if I have a web browser open it jitters around and keeps resizing the content. The only way to make it stop is to physically power cycle the machine. If I even just do a restart, it sometimes keeps happening.
I never had this problem on Ubuntu 14.4, it's only been after I switched to 16.4.
I'm using a Lenovo U530 laptop and Ubuntu 16.4. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Just enter below commands it will became proper

1. `dpkg --configure -a`
2. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. `reboot`

Comment: You must provide information on how this can solve the problem. Please update your answer and add more detail

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the problem persists even after following your instructions.